# Microsoft Graph API - General Exception during fetching Sites/root and drives

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, bearer-token

I created standalone application on node.js authorized in AAD with client/secret with permissions to access groups, sites, directories. I managed to create Teams group and team by Microsoft Graph API but when I tried to fetch `sites/root` or `drives`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/sites/root
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive
```

I received 500 Internal Server Error:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": (....),
      "date": "2020-01-31T09:15:17"
    }
  }
}
```

Is access to sites and drives possible by Graph API with app token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is causing by using "Group.Create","Group.ReadWrite.All" together

Comment: Hi @Paulina, That's very good to know, thank you for having dug further into it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. One possibility here is that if you are attempting to access the drive or site right after creating the team, they may not be provisioned yet. There is some delay that can happen, typically only a few minutes at most.

Comment: unfortunately it's not this case. Fetching sites and drives for this group is working in MS Graph Explorer for my account with admin permission but it's not working for my app

Comment: Hmm. Have you checked your access token at https://jwt.ms and confirm the permissions (contained in the `roles` claim)?

Comment: yes, I checked ["User.ReadWrite.All","Directory.ReadWrite.All","Sites.ReadWrite.All","Group.Create","Group.ReadWrite.All","Sites.Manage.All"]

Comment: Can you try reading Files.Read.All? I had that in my token when I tested it, wondering if that makes a difference.

Comment: I added - nothing new happened. I'm starting to thinking that app-only access is not enough

Comment: I just did it, so it is definitely enough :). To rule out your code, you might want to try using your token to send an API request directly via Postman or something similar.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue trying fetching information from a group's drive or site. I can get the members by doing https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members.
I am sure It is a permission issue but I can't see which one:
[ "User.ReadWrite.All", "People.Read.All","Group.Read.All","Directory.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All","Contacts.ReadWrite", "Group.Create", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "Files.ReadWrite.All","Directory.Read.All","User.Read.All","Files.Read.All", GroupMember.ReadWrite.All", "Group.Selected", "Notes.ReadWrite.All" ]
Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: @Geoff if it was the answer I'll gladly accept it - the problem is in "Group.Create","Group.ReadWrite.All" - together causes the 500 error. Now I know that the second one is enough ;) Thanks for hint

Answer (score 0):

When you [register your Azure Active Directory App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2), which supported account type are you choosing?

I had exactly the same issue as you, but I've created a new Azure AD App and changed the supported Account type back to the first option and all worked accordingly.
[image]

I hope this could help your issue.

Thank you.